# Calling mclapply from Rscript

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rscript, mclapply, rparallel

When calling a function which uses mclapply() with `Rscript myFuction.R --json=config.json` the mclapply functions fails with message

> all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code

However when I run the code within RStudio it runs fine. I'm developing on RStudio AWS AMI and testing in RStudio, and executing Rscript from the terminal of RStudio AWS machine, and the environments are the same between RStudio and the terminal.

Does anyone have an idea of extra parameters I might need to give to mclapply or other environment parameters I need to define when running mclapply with Rscript?

I've tried changing all the mclapply() arguments without success

Here is my environment.

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux 2

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /anaconda3/envs/r35p27/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets
[8] methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] rlist_0.4.6.1               stringi_1.4.3
 [3] stringr_1.3.1               seqinr_3.4-5
 [5] rBLAST_0.99.2               ShortRead_1.40.0
 [7] GenomicAlignments_1.18.1    SummarizedExperiment_1.12.0
 [9] DelayedArray_0.8.0          matrixStats_0.54.0
[11] Biobase_2.42.0              Rsamtools_1.34.0
[13] GenomicRanges_1.34.0        GenomeInfoDb_1.18.1
[15] Biostrings_2.50.2           XVector_0.22.0
[17] IRanges_2.16.0              S4Vectors_0.20.1
[19] BiocParallel_1.16.6         BiocGenerics_0.28.0
[21] aws.s3_0.3.12               jsonlite_1.5
[23] configr_0.3.3               optparse_1.6.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1             RColorBrewer_1.1-2     compiler_3.5.1
 [4] base64enc_0.1-3        bitops_1.0-6           tools_3.5.1
 [7] zlibbioc_1.28.0        digest_0.6.20          lattice_0.20-35
[10] Matrix_1.2-14          yaml_2.2.0             GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.1
[13] hwriter_1.3.2          httr_1.3.1             xml2_1.2.0
[16] ade4_1.7-13            grid_3.5.1             getopt_1.20.2
[19] data.table_1.12.2      glue_1.3.1             R6_2.2.2
[22] latticeExtra_0.6-28    magrittr_1.5           MASS_7.3-51.4
[25] aws.signature_0.5.0    ini_0.3.1              RCurl_1.95-4.12
[28] RcppTOML_0.1.6
```

Although this is a "Warning message" mclapply quits

```
Warning messages:
1: In mclapply(1:dim(this.split)[1], BLAST.loop, mc.preschedule = TRUE) :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

Comment: It likely happens because you have an error in your loop. `mclapply` does not debug similarly to `lapply`. Try running a subset of the data using a lapply loop, fix the errors and try again.

Comment: Thanks, good advice! I actually figured out that I had a variable that was not globally defined which was needed for the mclapply function...For any future readers, use `<<-` instead of `<-` to globally declare a variable which is passed to `mclapply`